# How to get the selected value on select tag using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html-select

I have a select statement like this:

```
<select onchange="change_session()" name="select_path" id="select_path">
    <option name="sserver_id" id="select_path" selected value="{{ i.id }}">{{ default_server_id }}</option>
    {% for i in all_server_id %}
        <option name="server_id" id="select_path" value="{{ i.id }}">{{ i.session_name }}</option>                 
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
```

The first option show the `default_id` on the top and the second options lists all the options. User can change the option and process accordingly which is send to server using AJAX. Now I want to find out which `server_id` has user selected using JavaScript like this:

```
var serverId=document.getElementById('server_id');
```

How can I get the selected option?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this..

```
<select onchange="change_session()" name="select_path" id="select_path">
    <option  selected value="{{ i.id }}">{{ default_server_id }}</option>
    {% for i in all_server_id %}
        <option  value="{{ i.id }}">{{ i.session_name }}</option>                 
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

code for javascript function

```
var serverId=document.getElementById('select_path').value;
```

Comment: Where does server_id come from?

Answer (score 8):

First, you need to remove the 'name' and 'id' attributes from your `<option>` tags. You cannot have duplicate ids on a single page.

Next, you can use this to get the element by id:

```
var selected = document.getElementById('select_path').value;
```

Answer (score 1):

> use this

```
<select id="MySelectOption">
    <option value="1">test1</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">test2</option>
    <option value="3">test3</option>
 </select>
```

> javascript

```js
<script>
       var e = document.getElementById("MySelectOption");
         var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
 </script>
```

> ```
> If you would like to get the actual text from the selected option do this:
> ```

```
<script>
       var e = document.getElementById("MySelectOption");
        var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
 </script>
```